# c# Do-While Calling back

Tags: c#, if-statement, return, switch-statement, do-while

I'm stuck in my code!

I have a Do -While Loop and inside I have Switch-Case and each case have  If Else Conditions like this :

Here is the problem 
Once I press the Retry Button(in If-Else Condition ) I want to go back in middle of the Do Loop and rerun it again for checking...
I'm not quite sure how I should do this.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Please try to use standard English capitalization and punctuation in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the switch case is at the bottom of the loop body, you could just call `continue` and the loop with reiterate from the start.

If you need to start from the middle of the loop, and not the start, the only way I can think of is to wrap the middle in another loop body. Now `continue` will apply to the inner loop and you will get what you want.

If no other option, you can use [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but [beware the consequences](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)

Comment: "If no other option, you can use goto" ...but be aware of course that this will [cause yourself and others harm](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why you'd structure your code like this in a huge loop and switch statement. For me, I'd probably break that up. It would make it simpler to follow. But perhaps you have a reason.

If you can, create an inner loop and continue executing that loop until a non-retry value is returned.

If that really doesn't work, then I'm not above using `goto`. I know that's taboo for a lot of people but my goal is to write clear code. And if you know what you're doing and a `goto` results in the clearest code, then I say go for it.

Comment: `goto` is easy to abuse, but it's also easy to use in a clear and understandable way.

Comment: Right, the recommendation is that developers avoid `goto` altogether until they are very comfortable thinking in terms of more advanced constructs. But once a developer reaches that point, I think it's silly to never use `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to split your code into functions for readability and maintenance piont of view. I would suggest you to try this:

```
do
{
  if(eErrorCode!=0)
  {
     if( GetResult(eErrorCode) == "Break")
      break;
  }
}

private string GetResult(eErrorCode)
{
  switch(eErrorCode)
  ...
}
```